# How to find Duplicates in One Column based on a Value in Another Column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table like such:

| LOT | SEQ |
| --- | --- |
| LOT1 | 8 |
| LOT1 | 8 |
| LOT2 | 5 |
| LOT3 | 4 |
| LOT4 | 4 |
| LOT4 | 1 |
| LOT5 | 7 |

I would like to select duplicates in the ‘SEQ’ Column if they have the same value in the ‘LOT’ Column.

In the example table above, the desired query would give me LOT1 as the Answer, and the Repeated SEQ as 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a standard `group by` + `having`.

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (lot, seq)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'LOT1', 8 FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'LOT1', 8 FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'LOT2', 5 FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'LOT3', 4 FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 'LOT4', 4 FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT 'LOT4', 1 FROM DUAL
 15         UNION ALL
 16         SELECT 'LOT5', 7 FROM DUAL)
```

Query:

```
 17    SELECT lot, seq
 18      FROM test
 19  GROUP BY lot, seq
 20    HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;

LOT         SEQ
---- ----------
LOT1          8

SQL>
```

Comment: Please take 2 minutes before posting answers to search for duplicates and, if you find one, close the question.

Comment: I am very sorry. I was having difficulty phrasing my question and understanding it. So I decided to post in order to seek help.

Comment: No problem, John.